# Service-worker.js not available in the for debugging in the chrome dev tools

Tags: android-webview, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker

I understand service-worker runs as a separate thread parallel to the main thread. 
I have an android app that runs Webview. My app is in react and i use workbox strategies for caching. 
Service worker updates everytime I do a new build. However the source file of service-worker.js is not available in the chrome dev tools for me to debug. 
Any idea how i can get the file there so that i can put breakpoints and debug ?

PS: just few days before i could get the file for debugging the dev tools. I am not sure what has changed. I havent changed any settings the the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the exact same problem with the same symptoms and timeframe. I tried everything I can think of and can no longer get remote debugging of a service worker running in an Android WebView to work.

Like you I am **sure** it was working in mid-February and stopped working in the last few weeks.

I submitted a bug to Google which you can find [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=939603).

I think we can only hope it will be fixed in an upcoming release of Chrome.

Comment: This seems to be fixed in V74 of Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect your extension's service worker but it's tricky, I don't know why Chrome doesn't show the service worker in the default chrome extension devtools.

here is how you can do it:

1. open chrome://serviceworker-internals/?devtools
2. find your extension there, there is a textarea that shows console logs, every console log will show the extension path in chrome e.g.

`Console: {"lineNumber":688,"message":"[crx-helper] connection error","message_level":3,"sourceIdentifier":3,"sourceURL":"chrome-extension://aobpjedackhiamobjolncblfckdgfjbk/background.bundle.js"}`

3. get that **sourceUrl** `chrome-extension://aobpjedackhiamobjolncblfckdgfjbk/background.bundle.js` yours will have a different id, which you can also see in `chrome://extensions`
   paste that path in a new tab and open devtools (screenshot).

[image: extension path open]